# How do I divide a list into groups and store the indices?

Tags: c#, listbox, sorteddictionary

I have a list box which holds, say, 6 values. Using buttons it's possible to insert new items into the list box. I can move all of these items up and down using other buttons I've added. For the purpose of understanding we'll call the newly created items (which I want to act as groups/dividers) "groups". What I want to accomplish is to have the items between the groups stored. For example through a `SortedDictionary<int itemIndex, string group>`. An example (note that the bracketed number is the index):

```
Group 1 [0]
Item 1 [1]
Item 2 [2]
Item 3 [3]
Group 2 [4]
Item 4 [5]
Item 5 [6]
Group 3 [7]
Item 6 [8]
```

The dictionary could look like this:

```
1, "group 1"
2, "group 1"
3, "group 1"
5, "group 2"
6, "group 2"
8, "group 3"
```

Where the first number is an item index in the list box and the second (string) is the group it falls under.

So my question is: how do I loop the list box in such a way that I can check which items fall under what group? If there's an easier way of doing it (using a different control than a list box) I'm happy to try that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve it myself and this is how:

```
        // Create string to save last 'used' group in.
        string lastGroup = string.Empty;

        // Create counter to check what index we are at in the ListBox.
        int i = 0;

        // Create a dictionary to store <string Item, string Group>.
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

        // Loop every item (as string) in the ListBox.
        foreach (string o in lbxMain.Items)
        {
            // If the item is a group:
            if (o.StartsWith("Group:"))
                // Put the name of the item into the lastGroup variable so we know where to put the items in.
                lastGroup = lbxMain.Items[i].ToString();

            // If the item is an item:
            if (o.StartsWith("Item:"))
                // Put the item into a dictionary with the lastGroup variable saying what group it's part of.
                dictionary .Add(o + " " + i, lastGroup);

            // Increase i so we keep an eye on the indices.
            i++;
        }
```

And if you just want the code:

```
        string lastGroup = string.Empty;
        int i = 0;
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

        foreach (string o in lbxMain.Items)
        {
            if (o.StartsWith("Group:"))
                lastGroup = lbxMain.Items[i].ToString();
            if (o.StartsWith("Item:"))
                dictionary.Add(o + " " + i, lastGroup);
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean winforms, `ListView` has `.Groups` (each of `ListViewGroup`) built in, with each `ListViewItem` having a `.Group`. This should make what you need easy in the code, and visually intuitive for the user.

Note that groups are only displayed when the `.View` is `View.Details`, `.ShowGroups` is `true`, and visual styling is enabled (`Application.EnableVisualStyles()`, usually in `Main()`).

Comment: Thank you for your response. This would make certainly make it easier, but I would like to stick to the same lay out as a list box. Is there a way to make the `ListView` look like one?